# Find $x(t)$ given $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

> For  $0 \leq t \leq 1$ , a particle is moving along a curve so that its position at time  $t$  is  $(x(t),y(t))$. At time  $t=0$ , the particle is at position $(0,0)$ .
>
> We are given that
>
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{t}{\sqrt {1+t^2}}$$
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \sqrt {\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}$$
>
> Find $x(t)$

Here is my work:

$$x(t)=\int \frac{dx}{dt}= \int \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$

Substituting:

$$u=t^2+1 \implies du= 2t dt$$

We get;

$$x(t) = \int \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt = \sqrt{t^2+1}+C$$

Since it is asking for $x(t)$ and not $y(t)$ I believe I'm ok

Comment: $x$ should be replaced with $t$, since $x(t)$ is a function of $t$. Also, you can check that $C=-1$.

Comment: In the future, if all you need is a confirmation about if you integrated correctly and nothing more, please check Wolfram|Alpha first. Here’s an [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%E2%80%99+%3D+t%2Fsqrt%281%2Bt%C2%B2%29%2C+x%280%29%3D0) of how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is alright except for the $+ C$, notice that the question gave you that $x(0)=y(0)=0$, so that gives 
$$x(t)=\sqrt{t^2+1}-1$$